# CRUD for global constants array codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

I have an array defined in the constants.php file:

```
define('cancel_reasons', json_encode(array( 
'Service(s) are no longer needed',
'Choosing another company to work with',
'Disatisfied with service(s) provided',
'Service(s) are too expensive', )));
```

I want to know how I can perform crud operations on this array.  In my dashboard view, I have a button called "cancel reasons" which I send to a controller, and loads a page which reads the current items in the array.  Here is my code for reading the array in the controller page which displays as a dropdown select option:

```
public function crudCancelConstants() {
     //View array of cancel_reasons in constants.php
     $reasons = json_decode(cancel_reasons);
     echo '<h5> View all cancellation reasons below: </h5>';
     echo '<select>';
         echo '<option value="Select" selected>View Reasons</option>';
         foreach ($reasons as $key => $value) {
             echo ('<option value="'.$reasons.'">'.$value.'</option>');
             }
             echo '<select>';
 }
```

So how do I go about adding "add, delete, and edit" functionality to this array?  Also, would passing this array into a view instead of a controller make it easier to implement?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: ["constant: Unchanged through time or space; permanent."](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/constant#English) Declaring something as a constant, and then wondering how to edit it, suggests some confusion in your design. If you want this to be editable, put it somewhere intended for changing data, like a database, or even just a text file, rather than in a PHP constant.

Comment: The task my boss gave me (which his client gave him) was to add a new section called "cancel reasons" in the global settings.  Another task I have is that "users should be able to add/edit/delete their own cancellation reasons (CRUD)."  Should I voice the concerns you're bringing up to my boss?  I am an intern btw, and not only this, but most of the other directions I've been given have been confusing or contradictory like this...

Comment: I don't see how that requirement contradicts my suggestion that it should be moved into a database (or whatever general data store your application normally uses). It sounds like a top-level requirement, that may need to be broken down into multiple smaller tasks to tackle it; that's very normal, but something you probably need support with if you're just starting out. Rather than "voicing concerns", I think you should *present a suggested implementation*, involving replacing the current constant with something else, and see if your manager has any feedback, or prefers an alternative approach.